# EC2 not running userdata which is entered by boto3

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have the following userdata for my EC2 instance:

```
user_data = """#!/usr/bin/env bash
wget -O <>.pem '{}'
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install -y python-pip git awscli
sudo pip install boto markupsafe boto3 ansible python-dateutil futures
git clone https://< user >:< repo >.git
ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod 400 <>.pem
""".format(url)
```

The instance is being launched via the following boto3 command:

```
instances = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=ubuntu_image, MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, InstanceType='m3.medium', \
                                 KeyName=keyname, SubnetId='<>', SecurityGroupIds=['sg-<>'],
                                 UserData=user_data)
```

However, when I ssh and check in the instance once it is launched, I don't find any cloned repo.

Also, when I do `import ansible` inside the Python shell, I get the "module not found" error, which means that the userdata have not been executed.

**Where did I go wrong here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH into the instance then use a tool such as cURL to retrieve user data.

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data`

Another place to check might be log files in `/var/log`

Answer (score 1):

Adding logging helped me solve the issue. Apparently, `pip install ansible` is throwing some errors, which makes the script stop there, and the subsequent tasks aren't being executed.

I moved it to the bottom, and it works alright.

PS: All the files which you `wget` or download or clone, gets added to the root directory `/` and not `/home/ubuntu/`. [Had to `locate` the pem file to understand this.]